# Creating lists of files with specific beginings and endings

Tags: python, python-os

What I am trying to achieve is creating lists for each file that begins with a certain number and ends with ".shp". One list for all files that begins with 1 and ends with ".shp", one for all files that begins with 2 and ends with ".shp" and so on.

This is the snippet I'm working with:

```
from os.path import normpath
import os

path_temp2 = normpath(r'C:\\Users\\tlind\\Dropbox\\Documents\\Temp\\temp2layers\\')

merge_list = os.listdir(path_temp2)

for i in range(1,13):
    test = []
    check = str(i)
    res = [idx for idx in merge_list if idx.lower().startswith(check.lower())]
    test.append(res)

    for file in test:
        test2 = []
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            test2.append(file)
        
        print(test2)
```

It returns:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

EDIT:
This almost solves it:

```
from os.path import normpath
import os

path_temp2 = normpath(r'C:\\Users\\tlind\\Dropbox\\Documents\\Temp\\temp2layers\\')

merge_list = os.listdir(path_temp2)

for i in range(1,13):
    check = str(i)
    name_ext_matches = []
    name_matches = [idx for idx in merge_list if idx.lower().startswith(check.lower())]

    for file in name_matches:
    
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            name_ext_matches.append(file)
    
    print(name_ext_matches)
```

There's a big DOH in this one. The first list includes 10, 11 and 12 of course. I need to find a way to work my way around that. Any one with any suggestions?

Comment: `file` is actually a list....

Comment: `res` is a list, and you're appending it to a list, so you'll end up with a list of lists.

Comment: @schmack updated to the post. Perhaps you can help me out now?

Comment: @MattDMo updated to the post. Perhaps you can help me out now?

Comment: @TobiasBowley if you have a new problem with different code and different results, please ask a new question. Please include hard-coded example input, the output you're getting with the code, and the output you expect.

Comment: This seems like either a typo or a duplicate of e.g. [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703).

Answer (score 2):

`list` has no attribute `endswith` because you've made `test` a list of lists. You should be assigning to `test`, what you are currently assigning to `res`, or you should be iterating over `res` instead of `test`.

Right now, the value of `test` is a list whose first and only element is another list, which contains all the files which start with the string-value of `i`.

You can do something like:

```py
for i in range(1,13):
    check = str(i)
    # all files starting with the string-value of `i`
    name_matches = [idx for idx in merge_list if idx.lower().startswith(check.lower())]

    for file in name_matches:
        # all files that start with `i` AND end with `.shp`
        name_ext_matches = []
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            name_ext_matches.append(file)
        
        print(name_ext_matches)
```

Comment: This kind of works but it outputs loads of lists not just 12, which is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is "name_matches" minus everything but the .shp, basically.

Comment: I've updated the post to use another approach. Perhaps you can shine some light now?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding an underscore at the end of the number:

```
from os.path import normpath
import os

path_temp2 = normpath(r'C:\\Users\\tlind\\Dropbox\\Documents\\Temp\\temp2layers\\')

merge_list = os.listdir(path_temp2)

for i in range(1,13):
    check = str(i)+'_'
    name_ext_matches = []
    name_matches = [idx for idx in merge_list if idx.lower().startswith(check.lower())]

    for file in name_matches:
    
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            name_ext_matches.append(file)
    
    print(name_ext_matches)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).